# sql query group by day of month

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a record table that icludes dates of rows created. (oracle db)

```
ID    City       CreateDate
1     city-1     12.12.2017
1     city-2     13.12.2017
1     city-1     13.12.2017
1     city-3     12.12.2017
....
....
```

I want to create a daiy report in a month. For example City-1 report by days in December

```
Day    Count
1      10
2      80
3      60
4      10
...
30     11
```

Comment: Hint:  `extract(day from createdate)`.

Comment: Could rows be missing for a city on some days in the month?

Comment: You you want to group 1st of December and 1st of January together? And what about 1st of January 2017 and 1st of January 2018?

Comment: The OP said that he needs "daily report in a month", so there won't be 1st of December and January as month should be included into the WHERE condition.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you can use extract with count functions:

```
SELECT EXTRACT(day FROM CreateDate) "Day",
      COUNT(CreateDate) "Number of Reports"
      FROM yourTableName
      GROUP BY EXTRACT(day FROM CreateDate)
      ORDER BY "Number of Reports" ASC;
```

Answer (score 1):

If I understood it correctly, the following query will generate the report you wanted for December.

`SELECT EXTRACT(day FROM CreateDate) "Day", COUNT(*) "Count" FROM your_record_table WHERE EXTRACT(month FROM CreateDate) = 12 GROUP BY EXTRACT(day FROM CreateDate) ORDER BY EXTRACT(day FROM CreateDate);`