# Sql select by grouping multiple column

Tags: sql, oracle, pivot

I have a record table that icludes dates of rows created. (oracle db)

```
ID    City       CreateDate
1     city-1     12.12.2017
1     city-2     13.12.2017
1     city-1     13.12.2017
1     city-3     12.12.2017
....
....
```

I can create a daily report in a month [(from this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47953975/sql-query-group-by-day-of-month/47954125#47954125)). For example City-1 report by days in December.

```
SELECT EXTRACT(day FROM CreateDate) "Day",
      COUNT(CreateDate) "Number of Reports"
      FROM yourTableName
WHERE 
      EXTRACT(MONTH FROM CreateDate) = 12 AND 
      EXTRACT(YEAR FROM CreateDate) = 2017   
GROUP BY EXTRACT(day FROM CreateDate)
```

But I need to select and group multiple columns like this.

```
Day    City-1   City-2  City-3
1      10        5
2      80        60
3      60        42
4      10        37
...    ...       ...
30     11        12
```

Can sql query produce a result?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use conditional aggregation:

```
SELECT EXTRACT(day FROM CreateDate) as Day,
       SUM(CASE WHEN City = 'City-1' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as cnt_city1,
       SUM(CASE WHEN City = 'City-2' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as cnt_city2,
       SUM(CASE WHEN City = 'City-3' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as cnt_city3
FROM yourTableName
WHERE CreateDate >= DATE '2017-12-01' AND CreateDate < DATE '2018-01-01'
GROUP BY EXTRACT(day FROM CreateDate)
ORDER BY EXTRACT(day FROM CreateDate);
```

Notes:

- I changed the `WHERE` conditions to directly compare dates.  The use of `EXTRACT()` makes it much harder for Oracle to use an index.
- I added an `ORDER BY`, so the results are guaranteed to be in day order.
- I changed the names of the columns so they do not need to be escaped.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the desired result with the aid of pivoting as in the following :

```
WITH t AS
(
SELECT EXTRACT(day FROM CreateDate) Day,
      city
      FROM yourTableName
WHERE 
      EXTRACT(MONTH FROM CreateDate) = '12' AND 
      EXTRACT(YEAR FROM CreateDate) = '2017'   
GROUP BY EXTRACT(day FROM CreateDate), city
) 
select * from t
PIVOT 
(
  count(*) 
  for (city) in ('city-1' as city1, 'city-2' as city2, 'city-3' as city3 )
 )
 ORDER BY DAY;
```

[D e m o](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/458eec/20)

By the way, i recommend you use with bind variables as following :

```
WITH t AS
(
SELECT EXTRACT(day FROM CreateDate) Day,
      city
      FROM yourTableName
WHERE EXTRACT(MONTH FROM CreateDate) = '&i_month' -- 12
  AND EXTRACT(YEAR FROM CreateDate) = '&i_year'   -- 2017
GROUP BY EXTRACT(day FROM CreateDate), city
) 
select * from t
PIVOT 
(
  count(*) 
  for (city) in ('city-1' as city1, 'city-2' as city2, 'city-3' as city3 )
 )
 ORDER BY DAY;
```

which makes the query parametrical with using bind variables instead of literals. In this way your sql not needed to be parsed in every call, and wait time is reduced.